# Intersection Observer issue when user scrolls fast and ref object stays on the view

Tags: intersection, intersection-observer

I have issues with Intersection Observer only if user scrolls the bar fast, or force the scroll to stay at the button.

Unfortunately, the new data arrives, but since user holds the scrollbar down, the ref object stays on the view.

This issue happens if user scrolls fast or holds the scrollbar. Although new data is received and the loading box needs to be pushed down, but user manually keep it up. So observer won't detect the change.

User needs to scroll up and down again to loading happens to work again.

Is there anyway, to add a timmer to the component, to see if after 2 seconds still the loading box is in the view and calls the endpoint? 
in other words, how I can get the current status of IntersectionObserver. To see if it is currently visible or not?